# Connection pool issues on shared hosting with proper disposal

Tags: c#, sql-server

*I know that there is a similar question like this on Stack Overflow, but it doesn't quite fit what I have tried. I believe the reason for this problem is different, although the end-result is the same.*

Whenever my site has been running for about two or three days, I get the following error (which is obviously caused by either connections/queries hanging, or not being disposed properly).

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

At first, I did some investigation and realized that using `using`, using a `finalize` call and other solutions weren't enough. The error would still eventually occur.

So I decided to figure out wether or not the Server Explorer (which I use often) in Visual Studio leaks connections. I had already changed the maximum execution and connection timeout to 3 seconds, and had reduced the pool size to 10 connections, so the Server Explorer could be the cause. No luck!

So what do I try now?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the code I solved the problem with. When connecting, catch the exception and clear all pools, and then try again.

```
_connection =
    new SqlConnection(connectionString);
try
{
    _connection.Open();
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
    _connection.Open();
}
```

Also, when disposing the connection, make sure to clear the pools.

```
if (_connection != null)
{
    SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
    _connection.Close();
    _connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution. At best, you're treating the symptoms, not the problem.

Comment: It is a solution, since the problem is too many simultaneous users being signed in at the same time.

Comment: In that case the true solution would be to a) increase pool size and b) find leaks and fix them. Possibly c) hold connection open for a shorter duration.

Comment: I can't increase the pool size enough, since it is a shared host with master configurations. I tried (as I described) to decrease the timeout with no luck.

Comment: Will you (given that information, and given the fact that you didn't read the question properly) remove your downvote?

Comment: You can change the pool size using the connection string (web.config or SqlConnection ctor). I stand by my downvote as I would not recommend the procedure given here to anyone. Instead I recommend what I said earlier.; I think you're still leaking connections or screwing up pooled connections some other way. If this was not the case clearing the pool would not help.; (As the problem is solved for you you could delete the entire question, btw.)

Comment: I can replicate the issue simply by making a console program that opens 25 connections after eachother, where every IDisposable is disposed properly.

Comment: I do not believe that by itself. That would mean that ADO.NET is fundamentally broken in a way that would not have survived the past 10 years. Can you post a repro? Of course, if you convince me that ClearAllPools is the right solution (and I have never seen this) I'll convert the down- to an upvote. (I recommend that you just get rid of the question though).

Comment: After switching from UnoEuro to Azure, the problem no longer persists. I suspect it has to do with shared hosting?